# Best way to solve an integral including a nonparametric density and distribution

Tags: r, integration, numerical-methods

Suppose that I want to solve a function containing two integrals like (this is an example, the actual function is uglier)

[image]

where a and b are the boundaries, c and d are known parameters and f(x) and F(x) are the density and distribution of the random variable x. In my problem f(x) and F(x) are nonparametrically found, so that I know their values only for certain specific values of x. How would you set the integral?

I did:

```
# Create the data
val <- runif(300, min=1, max = 10) #use the uniform distribution
CDF <- (val - 1)/(10 - 1)
pdf <- 1 / (10 - 1)
data <- data.frame(val = val, CDF = CDF, pdf = pdf)

c = 2
d = 1

# Inner integral
integrand1 <- function(x) {
  i <- which.min(abs(x - data$val))
  FF <- data$CDF[i]
  ff <- data$pdf[i]
  (1 - FF)^(c/d) * ff
}

# Vectorize the inner integral
Integrand1 <- Vectorize(integrand1)

# Outer integral
integrand2 <- function(x){
  i <- which.min(abs(x - data$val))
  FF <- data$CDF[i]
  ff <- data$pdf[i]
  (quadgk(Integrand1, x, 10) / FF) * c * ff
}

# Vectorize the outer integral
Integrand2 <- Vectorize(integrand2)

# Solve
require(pracma)
quadgk(Integrand2, 1, 10)
```

The integral is extremely slow. Is there a better way to solve this? Thank you.

---------EDIT---------

In my problem the pdf and CDF are computed from a vector of values `v` as follows:

```
# Create the original data
v <- runif(300, min = 1, max = 10)
require(np)

# Compute the CDF and pdf
v.CDF.bw <- npudistbw(dat = v, bandwidth.compute = TRUE, ckertype = "gaussian")
v.pdf.bw <- npudensbw(dat = v, bandwidth.compute = TRUE, ckertype = "gaussian")

# Extend v on a grid (I add this step because the v vector in my data
# is not very large. In this way I approximate the estimated pdf and CDF
# on a grid)
val <- seq(from = min(v), to = max(v), length.out = 1000)
data <- data.frame(val)
CDF <- npudist(bws = v.CDF.bw, newdata = data$val, edat = data )
pdf <- npudens(bws = v.pdf.bw, newdata = data$val, edat = data )
data$CDF <- CDF$dist
data$pdf <- pdf$dens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `approxfun`?

It takes vectors x and y and gives you a function that linearly interpolates between those. So for example, try

```
x <- runif(1000)+runif(1000)+2*(runif(1000)^2)
dx <- density(x)
fa <- approxfun(dx$x,dx$y)
curve(fa,0,2)
fa(0.4)
```

You should be able to call it using your gridded evaluations. It may be faster than what you're doing (as well as more accurate)

(edit: yes, as you say, `splinefun` should be fine if its fast enough for your needs)

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, unfortunately this is just a toy example, may real integral is uglier. My main question was about the way I create the CDF and pdf in the integrate1 and integrate2 function (e.g., `FF <- data$CDF[i]` and `ff <- data$pdf[i]`). I think that it is that search algorithm that slows down the computation. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do there, to be honest; are you just saying the cdf is the cdf of the nearest known value? ... and the same for the pdf? (then the two would be making inconsistent assumptions) Perhaps an explanation with more details about what you're attempting to do there would help. How was the nonparametric calculation of cdf and pdf done? There may be neat things that could be done if the circumstances were clearer there.

Comment: Sure. I added how I generate the data in the question above. I have a vector of data `v` on which I use to create the `pdf` and `CDF` with the `np` package and I approximate them on a grid (`val`)

Comment: Oh, okay -- that's helpful I think there's defnite potential to speed this up. I'll have to come back though.

Comment: Thank you so much @Glen_b! I'm burning my pc on this! :/ I do believe that the problem is the searching algorithm because if I remove it and transform the inner integral into just `\int_x^b s ds` `R` finds a solution in a decent time.

Comment: This is rather simpler than what I am thinking about, but have you considered using `approxfun`?

Comment: No I've never used it

Comment: it takes vectors x and y and gives you a function that linearly interpolates between those. So for example, try  `x=runif(1000)+runif(1000)+2*(runif(1000)^2);` 
`dx=density(x);` 
`fa=approxfun(dx$x,dx$y);` 
`curve(fa,0,2);` `fa(0.4)` ....
 you should be able to call it using your gridded evaluations. It may be faster than what you're doing (as well as more accurate)

Comment: yes I checked it using https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/approxfun it's pretty cool. I could even try `splinefun`. I don't know how faster it will be though. It's still running.

Comment: If that's too slow you could perhaps avoid the overhead in `approxfun` by dealing with the setup part yourself and calling `C_ApproxTest` (2nd last line of it) directly, or by doing something similar with approx.

Comment: It's actually not too slow. I think I'll work with the `splinefun`, probably better than linear interpolation. I have a last question for you: `quadgk` or `integrate`? Thank you so much!

Comment: quadgk is Gaussian quadrature?

Comment: Yes https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/quadgk. If I use `integrate` I often get error `maximum number of subdivisions reached`

Comment: Well they're both using Gaussian quadrature then. The benefits of one over the other would depend on implementation details and possibly on exact details of your function and how you call them. I can't really say much useful other than if it's giving you accurate answers (e.g. pdf integrates to 1) you're probably fine either way.   ...  I will move some of my comments up and replace my earlier answer.

Comment: I realise you gave just an example, but in the integral shown, since f(x)/F(x) is d/dx log( F(x)) integration by parts will transform the example into two single integrals.

Comment: @dmuir did you notice the $x$ on the lower limit of the inner integral?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, and that means the derivative of the inner integral wrt x is the -ve integrand at x, and so integration by parts will transform the repeated integral into two single ones.

Comment: @dmuir Ah, now I see what you're getting at. Cool.